# How to generate RSA key using sha512 for JWT?

Tags: json, rsa, jwt, sha512

I understand that RSA keys can be generated using different `sha` algorithms. Using `openssl`, I don't seem to have the option of specifying what algorithm the key generator should use. I suspect it's using `sha256`.

How can I generate RSA keys using different `sha` algorithms (such as `sha512`) in either a bash shell or in Ruby? Does the `openssl` library support generating RSA keys using different algorithms? If not, does anyone know of another library I can use? (In ruby, `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` doesn't seem to allow for choosing an algorithm, but the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html) is hard for me to follow soo...?)

Apologies if this question has already been answered, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Maybe I should also note (in case I am wrong): it is my understanding that choosing a size for the generated RSA key (i.e. `RSA 2048`) is separate from choosing the hashing algorithm (i.e. `sha512`).

**UPDATE - Some background**

I want to sign Java Web Tokens with an RSA key. The [JWT library](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) I'm using gives me the impression that RSA keys can be generated using different hashing algorithms (RS256, RS384, RS512). Generating a key using `openssl` doesn't seem to let me choose what hashing algorithm is used though.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generating RSA keys with a sha algorithm". RSA keys are *generated* using carefully designed cryptographic random number generators. Under the hood these may make use of cryptographic hash functions like sha512 as one piece of the algorithm, but you would typically treat these as a black box for the purpose of key generation.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - I'm guessing (and its just a guess) that its either: (1) the underlying PRNG (like Java using SHA1 for `SecureRandom`); or (2) the signing algorithm associated with a digital signature (like used in a certificate). In either case I think we need more information or clarification.

Comment: @John - RSA keys are generated with random bits by choosing `p`, `q`, selecting `e` and then solving for `d`. There are some other constraints, like ensuring `p` and `q` are prime, and `e` is relatively prime or coprime to `ϕ(n)`. Hashes are not used at this stage in the process.

Comment: @jww, do you have any idea why the JWT library https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt would ask me to specify what hash algorithm was used to generate the RSA key? It sounds like you're saying every RSA key generation library (such as `openssl`) only allows you to select the number of bits in the key, not the algorithm used. Thanks!

Comment: (Navigating to github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt and scrolling down to the "RSA" section should show you what I'm referring to)

Comment: @John - When the sections states *"RS256 - RSA using SHA-256 hash algorithm"*, the RSA key is already generated. SHA and other hashes are used in the signing process; not the RSA key generation process.

Comment: @jww Ohhhh!!!! Thanks!! That distinction was lost on me. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks so much for your time jww & JamesKPolk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**RSA keys**, and "the RSA algorithm" don't have any notion of a hash algorithm.

An RSA key is just two prime numbers and one other number (from the (`p`, `q`, `e`) triplet all the other values can be derived). `e` is usually chosen as 0x010001 (though other reasonable values exist) and `p` and `q` are generated randomly (while almost any CSPRNG is going to have a backing hash algorithm the CSPRNG itself is usually considered a black box that just emits randomness).

Where a hash algorithm comes into play is in **RSA Signatures**.

For an RSA Signature the original data is hashed under an algorithm and then the hash value, algorithm identifier, and private key are used to produce a signature (for PKCS v1.5 signatures... for PSS there's also a second (effectively fixed) identifier and some more random bytes).

RS256 is the JWA ([JSON Web Algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518)) identifier for "**R**SASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using **S**HA(-2)-**256**".

[JWA section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.3) says

> This section defines the use of the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 digital
> signature algorithm as defined in Section 8.2 of RFC 3447 [RFC3447]
> (commonly known as PKCS #1), using SHA-2 [SHS] hash functions.

A key of size 2048 bits or larger MUST be used with these algorithms.

> 

The RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 SHA-256 digital signature is generated as
follows: generate a digital signature of the JWS Signing Input using
RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5-SIGN and the SHA-256 hash function with **the desired
private key**.  This is the JWS Signature value.

(emphasis mine)

So no requirement is made on the RSA key, other than that the spec was written in 2015 so they mandated a 2015-compatible minimum keysize.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!! @jww ended up answering my question in a comment (above) yesterday, but this is a much more detailed answer. The distinction between RSA generation and RSA signing was (previously) being lost on me.